# Is the Sum of Positive Numbers Minimized when Equal?

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

According to A.M G.M inequality:

$(a+b)/2\geq\sqrt{ab}$, for all $a,b>0$.

The equality holds when $(a = b)$, and when this condition is satisfied, the LHS expression attains its minimum value. Does this mean that the sum of two positive numbers is at its minimum when they are equal? What have I misunderstood here?

Comment: the RHS is not a constant. If the right hand side were a constant, then your argument would be correct. In this situation, $ a=b = 2$ yields $ (a+b)/2 = 2$, but it's by no means the minimum. put a = 1 and b = 1.5, then  $(a+b)/2 = 1.25 < 2$

Comment: The sum of two positive numbers is close to its minimum when the positive numbers are both close to $0$.  If their product is fixed at $k$ then their sum is minimised at $2\sqrt{k}$ when they are equal to each other and bot equal to  $\sqrt{k}$

Comment: What meaning has for you the statement "the sum of two positive numbers is at its minimum" f(n,m)=n+m has a minimum at n,m minimal so excluding 0 n=m=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that $ab=c$ where $c$ is a constant, then, in this case, $a+b$ will be minimised when $a=b=\sqrt{c}$.

If you know that $a+b=c$ where $c$ is a constant, then, in this case, $ab$ will be maximised when $a=b=c/2$.

If you don't know any of these, you cannot use the word "minimised" or "maximised" because these words are used with respect to a constant. All the statement tells us otherwise is that $\dfrac{a+b}{2}\geq\sqrt{ab}$. That's all.